# How to pass only Error messages from Model to Controller (Mongoose)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm building my node.js api and want to pass on the callback only messages about errors. Now I need to have a deal with object like this

```
{
    "success": false,
    "msg": {
        "errors": {
            "email": {
                "message": "test@tes is not a valid email!",
                "name": "ValidatorError",
                "properties": {
                    "type": "user defined",
                    "message": "{VALUE} is not a valid email!",
                    "path": "email",
                    "value": "test@tes"
                },
                "kind": "user defined",
                "path": "email",
                "value": "test@tes"
            },
            "username": {
                "message": "The Username is not long enough",
                "name": "ValidatorError",
                "properties": {
                    "type": "user defined",
                    "message": "The Username is not long enough",
                    "path": "username",
                    "value": "te"
                },
                "kind": "user defined",
                "path": "username",
                "value": "te"
            }
        },
        "_message": "Users validation failed",
        "name": "ValidationError"
    }
}
```

Here is my code
**userModel.js**

```
/* Custom Validation */
const validator = (v)=> {
    return v.length > 5;
};
/* END of Custom Validation */

const UserSchema = new Schema({
        username: {
            type: String,
            validate: [
                validator,
                'The Username is not long enough'
            ],
            required: [true, 'The Username is required'],
            unique: true,
            lowercase: true
        },
        password: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, 'The Password is required']
        },
        email: {
            type: String,
            validate: [
                (v)=> { return /^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+\.)+[^<>()[\]\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/i.test(v)},
                '{VALUE} is not a valid email!'
            ],
            lowercase: true,
            required: true
        },
        role: {
            type: [{
                type: String,
                enum: ['user', 'manager', 'admin']
            }],
            default: ['user']
        },
        team: {
            type: [{
                type: String,
                enum: ['IHLO', 'ADULT&SH', 'IPJ', 'ISD', '']
            }],
            default: ['']
        },
        created_date: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        },

    });

    UserSchema.pre('save', ...

    UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = ...

    module.exports = mongoose.model('Users', UserSchema);
**userController.js**

    / Register new user
    exports.signup = (req, res)=> {

        let new_user = new User(req.body);
        new_user.save((err, new_user)=> {
            if (err)
                return res.json({success: false, msg: err});
            res.json({success: true, msg: `Successful created new user ${new_user.username}.`});
        });
    };
```

Of course I can make a function on the frontend that search for 'message' keys but for some records it could be more than 100 errors. Is it anyway how I can do it and do not pass the redundancy data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply parse the error object before sending it to the frontend.

Here's how you could do it with a loop.

```
if (err){
    let messages = [];
    for(let i in err){
        messages.push({
            field: i,
            message: err[i].message
        });
    }

    return res.json({success: false, msg: messages});
}
```

You could also use a library like lodash to make it a bit cleaner.

```
if (err){
    let messages = _.flatMap(err, (value, key) => { field: key, message: value.message });
    return res.json({success: false, msg: messages});
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but i'm trying to avoid parsing the object.

Comment: looks like in this case it's the best solution

Answer (score 0):

projections

`User.find({}, {messages: 1})`
or

`User.find({},'messages')`

the second parameter is projection [mongoose api](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find)

I think you can also do the `User.find({},'messages -_id')` to leave out _id but if you are using object you can do `{_id : 0}`

If you want to filter out objects with error messages:

you could use `.lean()` to make a real js object

do something like

```
User.find({}).lean()
.then(users =>{
  user.filter(e => e.name == "ValidationError")
})
```

Haven't tested

Comment: Can you actually use projection with the errors returned from the save?

Comment: @jackblank thanks for reply. do you mean to do something like this `// Register new user
exports.signup = (req, res)=> {
    let new_user = new User(req.body);

    new_user.save((err, new_user)=> {
        if (err){

            User.find({}).lean()
                .then(new_user =>{
                    new_user.filter(e => e.name == "ValidationError")
                });

            return res.json({success: false, msg: err});
        } else res.json({success: true, msg: 'Successful created new user ${new_user.username}.'});
    });
};` can not make it work so far

Comment: @jackblank looks like projections only for find/select methods not for save